# LLVM bytecode on Apples iOS platform

Tags: ios, llvm, bytecode, native-code

Is there a document how Apple handles the LLVM byte code on the iOS platform (iPhone and/or iPad) or do they use native code? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LLVM compiles to native code for iOS.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a link/PDF/paper for more detailed information?

Comment: Try this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CompilerTools/Conceptual/LLVMCompilerOverview/index.html as well as giving references for the architecture it includes the money quote: "In Xcode[…] the LLVM code generation layer (back end) turns that interim format into final machine code."